# How to set RelayState in SAML 2

Tags: spring, spring-boot, saml-2.0

Hi I am working on saml with the version 5.7.6 and wanted to set relay state.

- There is no `setRelayStateResolver(this::resolveCustomRelayState)` in `OpenSaml4AuthenticationRequestResolver`.
- `resolve()` method of Interface `Saml2AuthenticationRequestResolver` has return type `T extends AbstractSaml2AuthenticationRequest` and `AbstractSaml2AuthenticationRequest` is not eligible for inheritance outside package has default scope on constructor.

Also in `OpenSamlAuthenticationRequestResolver` class `relayState` is set as `String relayState = UUID.randomUUID().toString();`
which is of no use.

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/11065